# Does intel heat sink have film over compound?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

I just installed my new cpu and heat sink but did not check the bottom of the cooler to see if there was a film covering the thermal compound. Does anyone know if there is any?

Comment: Already installed it and have no more thermal paste.

Comment: All the intel cpu coolers that I've installed that are new always have (assuming it's a newer cpu). If for some reason yours didn't though, it's your money. I would check, or at least keep a close eye on temps... ASAP after starting it.

Comment: My ivy bridge didn't from what I recall, the packaging just kept the thermal compound away from anything that would mess it up.

Comment: Intel provides only a plastic cover to prevent particles from getting on the thermal pad they provide.

Comment: Just took it off, wadnt on there. It should be ok right? Only rrmoved heatsink for a second so no need for new paste right?

Comment: @Confuto It should work /alright/ as long as you don't put the CPU under high load, but removing the heatsink at all will introduce air pockets in the paste if you don't reapply new paste. You should reapply new paste when you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot all, all sorted. I am at 46-48 degrees when web browsing, downloading games and listening to music so this seems rather good; although I'll be replacing the paste ASAP. Was a little panic earlier, thanks all!